# WinAPI + Cmake + Aero

Tags: winapi, cmake, aero

I have a CMake project with an executable and a static library (linked to the exe). The library is responsible for implementing the creation of the window (using WinAPI for Windows OS), and the executable contains the main entry point (in this case a simple `int main(...)` function).

I've been googling for a day but cannot find a way to create a window with Aero support (can maximize by dropping to the top, the title bar is a little bit transparent, etc). I've read the [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) MSDN article but I'm not sure how I should handle this with CMake. Especially that the window implementation is hidden to the client (since it's implemented in the library).

The windowing code is really basic right now for simplicity. Some of the code will be refactored, the point is not that right now. Here is the (almost) full code for creating the window.

```
bool WindowsWindow::create(const WindowCreateInfo& info)
{
    // register custom window class
    {
        WNDCLASSEX wnd = { 0 };
        wnd.cbSize = sizeof(wnd);
        wnd.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
        wnd.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
        wnd.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
        wnd.style = CS_OWNDC;
        wnd.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW);
        wnd.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

        if (RegisterClassEx(&wnd) == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        hInstance = wnd.hInstance;
    }

    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(nullptr, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo;
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &monitorInfo);

    LONG style = 0;
    LONG exStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    int x = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    int y = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    int width = info.width;
    int height = info.height;

    if (info.isWindowed) {
        style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION;

        if (info.hasSysMenu) {
            style |= WS_SYSMENU;
        }
        if (info.allowMinimize) {
            style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        }
        if (info.allowMaximize) {
            style |= WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        }

        // ... positioning, adjusting size, etc.

    } else {
        style = WS_POPUP;
        x = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left;
        y = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top;
        width = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right - x;
        height = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom - y;
    }

    handle = CreateWindowEx(
        exStyle,
        CLASS_NAME,
        info.title,
        style,
        x,
        y,
        width,
        height,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr
    );

    if (!handle) {
        return false;
    }

    running = true;
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);

    return true;
}
```

The loop is the standard `Peek-Translate-Dispatch` trio and the `WndProc` only handles the `WM_CLOSE` message, otherwise returns with `DefWindowProc`.

- How could I enable the Aero support in this kind of setup?
- If the proper manifest file would be the solution, how should I handle it correctly? I mean the client (the executable) should not care that the underlying library is using WinAPI or not
- A CMake example would be really helpful

**Current solution**

I was able to find an example (actually from a Vulkan SDK) that pointed out that I need the `WS_THICKFRAME` style (a resize border) in order to my window become modern looking (Aero-like).

Comment: Actually it seems that the window style is the key here. Finally found an example where I was able to test things, and it seems that the WS_THICKFRAME style is required to get the desired effect(s). Seems logical since the window must be resized to dock it to the right for example. But still...

Comment: [Windows Aero can be enable](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-enable-windows-aero-fir-the-taskbar-and/1e716bb1-e2c2-4754-b5c5-f69823db2ac6) via configure/settings on Windows 7. Which windows version do you use? And are you talking about [Aero Snap feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) (for "maximize by dropping to the top")?

Comment: The Areo itself is enabled, only my own application was not displayed correctly. Adding the `WS_THICKFRAME` style to the window solves the issue tho.